# How to divide layout properly in nextJS13

Tags: next.js13, next-auth

I am creating additional child layouts authLayout and nextLayout to wrap the project. However, when I use it, it leads to errors and unexpected operations. authLayout and mainLayout are in nextJS's default layout.

```
import { options } from '@/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/options';
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';

export default async function AuthLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: ReactNode;
}) {
  const session = await getServerSession(options);

  return <div className="h-screen w-screen">{children}</div>;
}
```

How should I divide the layout properly and can you suggest me a way to check user authentication for navigation in this case?